# How do I make cryptsetup automatically use a key file during mount time?

Tags: crypt, luks

I am programmatically invoking cryptsetup and would like to pass in a key file on demand at the command line (not interactively).

How can I use cryptsetup with luks to take in a key file at the command line?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a keyfile:

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=32 count=1 of=/root/random_data_keyfile1
printf "YOUR PASSPHRASE" >/root/plaintext_passphrase_keyfile2
```

make the file read only to root:

```
sudo chmod 0400 /root/random_data_keyfile1
```

Add the key to LUKS:

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdX /root/random_data_keyfile1
```

You must add an entry to "/etc/crypttab":

```
echo "luks-$(cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sdX) UUID=$(cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sdX) /root/random_data_keyfile1" >>/etc/crypttab
```

reboot to make sure the device auto-unlocked. make sure you have the right device ID.

reference: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1121163